# Build Linux Kernel with randomized struct fields

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

I'm attempting to build the Linux Kernel (version 5.16).  I know that there's a compile-time option to randomize various structure fields (indicated by macros like `randomized_struct_fields_start`).  However, I'm looking through `make menuconfig` and I can't find the right option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options you need to enable are in “General architecture-dependent options”, but they depend on GCC plugins. For the latter to work,

```
$(gcc -print-file-name=plugin)/include/plugin-version.h
```

must exist; on Debian for example, that means you need to install `gcc-10-plugin-dev`.

Once that’s done, enable “GCC plugins”, then “Randomize layout of sensitive kernel structures”:

[image: Screenshot of the “General architecture-dependent options” menu]

[image: Screenshot of the “GCC plugins” menu]